# Firewall allows access from blocked IP range - Debian Jessie

Tags: linux, networking, debian, iptables

I have installed LFD/CSF firewall but can not block IP address range.

```
csf -d 172.111.221.0/24
Adding 172.111.221.0/24 to csf.deny and iptables DROP...
DROP  all opt -- in !lo out *  172.111.221.0/24  -> 0.0.0.0/0
DROP  all opt -- in * out !lo  0.0.0.0/0  -> 172.111.221.0/24
```

So, let's check IP tables:

```
iptables -nv -L

...
Chain DENYIN (1 references)

0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       172.111.221.0/24     0.0.0.0/0
Chain DENYOUT (1 references)

 0     0 DROP       all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            172.111.221.0/24

...
```

But it doesn't work. Spammer from IP address 172.111.221.34 still can acces smy website.

Comment: That rule certainly looks like it should drop packets from that range. If requests are still getting through, that implies that there's another rule earlier on in the `iptables` rules which is matching the packets and allowing them. Is there perhaps a rule which allows all web traffic (based on destination port)?

Comment: Maybe it's because I am using Cloudflare

Comment: Yes, it is because of Cloudflare. When using it, all connections to your server come from a CloudFlare IP address. You have to use something on the web server / application server level to block it.